# Export to formatted range

Tags: excel, sas

I run a set of SAS programs (in Enterprise Guide) once per week. The result of this program is a list of issues that need to be placed in a formatted spreadsheet. The size of the list changes every week.

Currently I use "proc export" to move my results to a new tab in an Excel file. I then copy these unformatted results and paste them into a formatted table.

Is it possible to skip the manual copy+paste part of this process and export directly to a formatted spread?

At a former project, I was able to do this using DDE, but that is not an option in enterprise guide.

Comment: Are the results from SAS the only thing in the table, or do you add other stuff?

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?  (Not EG version - it would probably be something starting with a 9, 9.3 9.4 etc.)

Comment: If your table only contains the data from SAS, you can specify it as a named range and export to that range.  I do not have ACCESS/PC File on my laptop, so I cannot confirm the functionality -- hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: Where's EG, on a server or run locally? If you create a table that's linked in Excel it should update automatically when you refresh your data source.

Comment: I think you've asked this on communities.sas.com and received this link, but I'll repeat it because it is helpful http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/A_Poor/Rich_SAS_Users_Proc_Export

Comment: You can do it the other way around: Write (or record) a VBA macro that either does the copy paste work or formats the output from SAS. The best solution depends on your answers to the above questions. Do you want help for VBA?

Comment: I am using SAS version 9.4 running on a server. I considered using a VBA macro, but I would like the entire process to run automatically. I'll give the name range thing a shot, but I thought a named range had to be a specific range of cells, and the number of rows returned varies from run to run.

Comment: I guess this isn't possible... I've looked everywhere on how to this and the only solution involves DDE.